# qmake — loop doesn't split line

Tags: qt, qmake

This is works as expected (removes files):

```
defineTest(removeFiles) {
    FILES_TO_DEL = $$shell_path($$1) # full paths
    RETURN = $$escape_expand(\n\t)
    for(FILE, FILES_TO_DEL){
        QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$RETURN $$QMAKE_DEL_FILE $$quote($$FILE)
    }
    export(QMAKE_POST_LINK)
}


FILES_TO_DEL = $$DESTDIR/imageformats/qicns.dll \
               $$DESTDIR/imageformats/qico.dll \
               $$DESTDIR/imageformats/qtga.dll \
               $$DESTDIR/imageformats/qtiff.dll \
               $$DESTDIR/imageformats/qwbmp.dll \
               $$DESTDIR/imageformats/qwebp.dll
removeFiles($$FILES_TO_DEL)
```

But better way doesn't remove anything:

```
defineTest(removeFilesInDir) {
    PATH_TO_DEL = $$shell_path($$1)
    FILES_TO_DEL = $$shell_path($$2)
    message($$PATH_TO_DEL)
    message($$FILES_TO_DEL)
    RETURN = $$escape_expand(\n\t)
    for(FILE, FILES_TO_DEL){
        message($$FILE)
        QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$RETURN $$QMAKE_DEL_FILE $$quote($${PATH_TO_DEL}$${FILE})
    }
    export(QMAKE_POST_LINK)
}


FDIR = $$DESTDIR/imageformats/
FFILES = qicns.dll qico.dll qtga.dll qtiff.dll qwbmp.dll qwebp.dll
removeFilesInDir($${FDIR}, $${FFILES})
```

`message($$PATH_TO_DEL)` shows correct path,
`message($$FILES_TO_DEL)` shows  `"qicns.dll qico.dll qtga.dll qtiff.dll qwbmp.dll qwebp.dll"` (as expected),
but `message($$FILE)` shows the same `"qicns.dll qico.dll qtga.dll qtiff.dll qwbmp.dll qwebp.dll"` (only ones).

**Why loop in `removeFilesInDir` doesn't split line the same way as in `removeFiles`? How to fix `removeFilesInDir` ?**

---

Windows, Qt 5.9, QtCreator, qmake at .pro and .pri files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's works. I remove `$$shell_path()` from `FILENAMES`:

```
# Remove some files from directory (directory_path and file_names)
defineTest(removeFilesInDir) {
    PATH = $$shell_path($${1}) # full path to directory
    FILENAMES = $${2}          # filenames inside directory for remove
    RETURN = $$escape_expand(\n\t)
    for(FILENAME, FILENAMES){
        QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$RETURN $$QMAKE_DEL_FILE $$quote($${PATH}$${FILENAME})
    }
    export(QMAKE_POST_LINK)
}
```

from [doc.qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#shell-path-path):

> **shell_path(path)**
>   Converts all directory separators within path to
>   separators that are compatible with the shell that is used while
>   building the project (that is, the shell that is invoked by the make
>   tool). For example, slashes are converted to backslashes when the
>   Windows shell is used.

I don't know why it's break loop.